# How to display full-length query in airflow UI log when using snowflake connector for Python

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, airflow, mwaa

For debugging purposes, I want to output the entire query when using the snowflake connector for Python in airflow.

I noticed that, before the actual execution of a query, the query gets printed out in a log, but I think airflow(?) abbreviates the output as something like the following in the log feature in airflow UI:

```
[2023-09-30, 09:04:26 UTC] {{cursor.py:710}} INFO - query: [SELECT *...]
```

In fact, in the cursor.py for the snowflake connector, it tries to output the query before the execution as in [this link](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-python/blob/main/src/snowflake/connector/cursor.py#L804C45-L804C66).

What I want is, to print out the entire query without being shortened/abbreviated.

How can I do this?

Alternatively, it is okay to suggest another way to display the full-length query. In particular, I am interested in knowing a way to output the query that is exectuted. I know that I could use the following snippet to output the query. But, when I use server-sider bining like numeric binding, it only shows something like `select :1 from my_table`, and `:1` part is left as is. I would like the final query where the `:1` gets replaced. any taker?

```py
cur.execute(sql_query, params)
cur.get_results_from_sfqid(cur.sfqid)
print(cur.query)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The following works:

```
from snowflake.connector.connection import DEFAULT_CONFIGURATION

DEFAULT_CONFIGURATION["log_max_query_length"] = (10000, int)
```